# websockets socket_select error

Tags: php, websocket, phpwebsocket

Hello im trying to implement a websocket communication between client and server. the problem is when im tring to start the server im getting this error in the command line

```
# php -q htdocs\socket\server\startDaemon.php
2012-07-23 10:10:02 System: Socket Resource id #7 cre
2012-07-23 10:10:02 System: Socket bound to localhost
2012-07-23 10:10:02 System: Start listening on Socket

Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\socket\server\socketWebSocket.class.php on line 35
```

The code in line 35 is the above:

```
$num_sockets = socket_select($changed_sockets,$write=NULL,$exceptions=NULL,NULL);
```

I have searched for answer but yet nothing works. Can anybody help me? Thanx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
$write=NULL;
$exceptions=NULL;

$num_sockets = socket_select($changed_sockets,$write,$exceptions, NULL);
```

Comment: this works! @lucky13: atleast mark this as the right answer please.